# Can I display a image in custom layout?

Tags: android

I know I can use the below code to display a image in system layout,
but I hope to display an image in my custom layout, how can I do that? Thanks!

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int id = v.getId();
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent,ForBrowse);
}



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/myreturn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you asking how to display an image from the xml layout file?

Comment: try by add imageView to your layout !

Comment: @Tarsem he has ImageView within his layout already.

Comment: @ObieMD5 he has written "I know I can use the following code to display a image " but he/she is desiring something else !

Comment: question to too vague what do you think?maybe a background?
try 
android:background="@drawable/background"

Comment: Thanks! The system layout for image provide many functions such as zoom in, zoom out, send and delete etc. So I hope to customzie the system layout and add my buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above resolutions are not ok, then try this one, it loads the image from tha page you want:

```
String url = "file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*";
Bitmap bmp = fromURL(url);
imgview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
and write this function:

public static Bitmap fromURL(String src) {  
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception exception1) {
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

after setting the xml up as you have done,

simply add the following code to set image to your imageview

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Imageview1);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourImageViewerActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putString("data", yourImageUri); 
intent.putExtras(bundle); 
startActivity(intent);
```

---

onCreate() method:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String yourImageUri= bundle.getString("data");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(yourImageUri);
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add an image to you layout from the XML file then

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/book"    <- Change this to your drawable item
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```